# Is there a way to import a variable from one file to the next? [Object-Orientated Programming]

Tags: python, selenium, oop, variables, element

Hi I have just learnt about Object Orientated Programming. However, recently I came across an issue...

I would like to ask if there is a way to import a variable from one file to the next, or possible any other way I can go about finding an element in *file2* using a value obtained from a method in *file1*.
I thought about importing the value saved within the **max_sim** variable found through my method in *file1* and use it within another locator in *file2*. However, I run into an error as **max_sim** is not recognized in my locators file (*file2*)

This *file1* contains all my **locators** for my bot program:

```
@property
def simulator_mod(self):
    locator = (By.XPATH, '//input[@value="' + str(max_sim) + '"]')
    return BaseElement(driver=self.driver, by=locator[0], value=locator[1])
```

This other *file2* contains all my **methods** that help me run my program:

```
class BaseElement(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, by, value):
        self.driver = driver
        self.value = value
        self.by = by
        self.locator = (self.by, self.value)
        self.web_element = None

    def find_elements(self):
        elements = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(locator=self.locator))
        self.web_element = elements
        return None

    def select_sim_element(self):
        self.find_elements()
        simulator_list = []
        simulator_elements = self.web_element
        breakpoint()
        for sim in simulator_elements:
            sim_list_val = sim.get_attribute("value")
            simulator_list.append(int(sim_list_val))
        max_sim = max(simulator_list)
        return max_sim
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it to a text file in file 1 and then read that file in file 2

```
#File 1: 
x=0
while x==0:
   variable_file = open("VariableFile.txt", "r+")
   variable_file.truncate() #This clears the file
   variable file = #Input the variable contents or variable here

#File 2:
x=0
while x==0:
    variable_file = open("VariableFile.txt", "r")\
    variable_in_file_2 = variable_file
    variable_file.close ()
```

Comment: Do i manually create the .txt file? If so, where do i put it? I tried putting it in the same folder as both my files but it gave FileNotFoundError

Comment: You would manually create the .txt file and put it in the same folder. If the file is not correctly named in the code it will not work

Comment: By the way, is there another way to go about doing this? I have to run multiple instance of the file, and this would require multiple text files for each file1 and this would probably be very messy.

Comment: This method should only require 1 file